# getting info from name attributes to $_POST[] using serializeArray()

Tags: php, jquery, post

I would like to get something like `$aentry = $_POST[a]` in a PHP file so I could echo out the input that the user enters to the page. I would like to do it by using serializeArray() because that is what I'm learning.

here is an example code for form:

```
<div><input type="text" name = "a" value = "1" id = "a"></div>
<div><input type="text" name = "b" value = "2" id = "b"></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name = "c" value = "3" id = "c"></div>
<div>
    <textarea name="d" id="" cols="40" rows="8">4</textarea>
</div>
<div><select name="e" id="">
    <option value="5" selected = "selected">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
...
```

from what I know about PHP is that in order to get the inforamtion the user entered you need to do something like this:

```
<?php 
 $aentry = $_POST[a]
 echo $aentry 
?>
```

I learned that by using serializeArray() you can get all the info in a form easer   in an array/object format and that you could use that to set up your super global arrays. I don't know how to do this.

So far  I got this:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var data =  JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
    $('.result').html(data);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I get this output:

```
[{"name":"a","value":"1"},{"name":"b","value":"2"},{"name":"c","value":"3"},{"name":"d","value":"4"},{"name":"e","value":"5"}]
```

How do I  set it up so it could be used like `$aentry = $_POST[a]` and that i could use the `$aentry` to process in PHP like I explained above? I would also like to  use the other input info aswell. If you could show me the code that would be awesome.
Sorry if this sound like a dumb question I'm new to this.

I guess I wont be needing the "value" key because I think I'm only interested in the name attribute because that is what php uses

Comment: since you are not using a ajax based form submit there is no need to manual serialization... when the form is submitted all input fields are serialized to request params and sent to server... what is the problem you are facing

Comment: What I want to do is learn how to get all the form input information using serialize array.lets say I wanted to do it the ajax way. I'm also a little confused in what serializeArray() is. I read the API. I feel like it is usefull but I dont know how to process the input so I could use the info to echo it out and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery AJAX to send you post data. here is the url: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
EDIT:

here a code you can use

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var data =  $(this).serializeArray();
              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'page.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                  $('.result').html(data);
                }
            });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

When you post the form it wil send the post values to page.php (change to your own page) and  it wil post it there.

EDIT:

If you add this code to page.php it wil return the post values:

```
<?php 
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

you can use your developer tools [Tab network] (in Chrome) to see the AJAX submit

Comment: Thanks for answering. explain to me by what you mean by posting it there. How would I use it. Thank you

Comment: maybe show a lil example of page.php. that would be helpful

Comment: edited the post, you get a post array on page.php so you can just handle the post.

Comment: Let me know if it works or if you have more questions

Comment: I understand it much better. I achieved printing the user information thanks to your help. as I was reading up on this people were doing stuff like this: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());. why use stringify. why does the api show   [link](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) [
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
] your way is much more simpler

Comment: jQuery: "The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string", Mozilla:"The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON" So the first convert it to an array or object second converts it to a JSON. But if you use the AJAX methode like above thats json is not needed .serializeArray() should be enough to send you form data with AJAX.

Comment: Oh I think because it is just showing javascript objects and `print_r($_POST);` is processing it through superglobals